# Blank options following Correct options in html select

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a select option and populated it with a mysqli query from the database. But there are blank options below the correct options in the dropdown menu. 
This is my php page with select option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    include("includes/connect.php");
    function getcats_add_products(){
        global $con;
        $get_cats="select * from categories";
        $run_cats=mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);                   
        echo "<option>Select Category</option>";

        while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
            echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_id, $cat_title<option>";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Panel - Add Products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/admin-style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">

    </header>
    <div class="heading">Add New Product</div>
    <div class="product-table-div">
        <form>
            <table class="product-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Category</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="product-table-input" >
                            <?php getcats_add_products(); ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>    
                    <td>Product Brand</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="" name="" id="product-table-input">
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Product title</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="" name="" id="product-table-input">
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Price</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="" name="" id="product-table-input">
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Product description</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="" name="" id="product-table-input">
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Product image</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="" name="" id="product-table-input">
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Keywords</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="" name="" id="product-table-input">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div id="product-submit-div">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="product-submit" value="Add">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>`enter code here`
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php getcats_add_products(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css file:

```
header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #006b00; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#006b00, #00fa00); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#006b00, #00fa00); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#006b00, #00fa00); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#006b00, #00fa00);
}

.heading {
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #001A00;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.product-table-div {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;

}

.product-table {
    table-layout: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #00CC8A;
}

.product-table td {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

#product-submit-div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#product-submit {
    border: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

This is my connect page:

```
<?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "ecommerce");
        if(!$con){
        die('connection error: '.$mysqli->connect_error());
    }
?>
```

This is how the select option is looking after populating with data:
[Select options followed by spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MvUq.png)

---

This is the table i am querying:
[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78yNv.png)

I cannot make sure if it is a mysql problem or css problem. The spaces are not between the first  tag and the second. There are blank options following only the  tags which i am pulling from the database.

Comment: It's just a typo. You're missing the proper closing tag where you're echoing the options. Just adding the `/` in that `<option>` should fix it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Can I just point out that in addition to the errors mentioned in the answers, you also have 1) `type=""`, and 2) identical ids in all the inputs, which also is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing closing tag, therefore, you get additional empty space after each option.

```
echo "<option value='".$cat_id."'>".$cat_title."</option>";
```

This is the reason why you're getting empty line after each select option.

Comment: You're right about the closing tag, but variable interpolation is not incorrect. There's no need to change it to concatenation instead.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Oops, yes, it's true. But I think it's prettier and easier to understand when using what I have written before. But to avoid confusion I have remove that part.

Comment: Yes, that's embarassing. Thanks for the answer. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You have added two time the Start of the HTML document and that it not advisable and you have to remove that from the code.

Remove two time that you have added `<!DOCTYPE html>`

**Reason for not displaying the Options in the select tag:**

You have not concatenated the string properly over the echo that you have added onto the select tag. Hence your select tag will not display any value in the option value and you need to change the entire function like this in order to display the values over to the option tag.

> Instead of using the `mysqli_fetch_array()` you can use the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and you can get the single row at a time in the while loop so that you can modify the data as needed. Like the same you need to follow for the `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

1. `mysqli_fetch_array()` - Method

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
    include("includes/connect.php");
    function getcats_add_products(){
        global $con;
        $get_cats="select * from categories";
        $run_cats=mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);                   
        echo "<option>Select Category</option>";

        while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
            echo "<option value=".$cat_id.">".$cat_title."<option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

2. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`- Method

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
    include("includes/connect.php");
    function getcats_add_products(){
        global $con;
        $get_cats="select * from categories";
        $run_cats=mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);                   
        echo "<option>Select Category</option>";

        while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_cats)){
            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
            echo "<option value=".$cat_id.">".$cat_title."<option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Note:** Both will follow up the same methods of the looping structure so that you can decide which one to use and both are the same as you see when it displays the output.

But see to that in the above code how the concatenation is done and you have to do like this alone.

And in the default way you have to pass the ID or Value in the option value and then One more parameter in the Outside of the Option value.

**Replace:**

```
echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_id, $cat_title<option>";
```

**With:**

```
echo "<option value=".$cat_id.">".$cat_title."<option>";
```

Hope so my explanation would be clear and you can rectify it for future purposes.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Well, that's better than my answer but I hope both answers are helpful. :) *EDIT*: note that it should be `".$cat_title."` not `'".$cat_title."'` as your option will print with `'` at both sides.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas. Thanks:) I have modified my answer removing the quotes that i have added has extra to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @EdvinTenovimas. I am wandering why they have given negative vote for this answer :)